# howto pass an argument to an android app, which is started through shell command

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a command which starts an android app (apk) per shell command, which works great.

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.MyActivity
```

How can I pass an argument to that command, which I can read in my app again ?

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.MyActivity <MyArgument>
```

and howto read the parameter in the activity ?

```
sMyParam = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MyArgument");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs for [specifying intents with shell commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec).

The bits of most likely interest to you are:

```
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>
Add string data as a key-value pair. 
--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE>
Add boolean data as a key-value pair. 
--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>
Add integer data as a key-value pair.
```

Answer (score 2):

As per this [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec) you can use `-e` option for String.

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -e KEY VALUE -n mypackage/.MyActivity
```